# Does the trust fund have the funds needed to cover the shortfall from a gas tax holiday?

Tags: united-states, taxes, infrastructure

In 1956, the federal motor fuel tax was established, along with a dedicated pool of money for the construction of an interstate highway system.   Those gas tax funds go into the "Highway Trust Fund".

Recently, Joe Biden has proposed a "tax holiday" to lower the price of gas.  This would necessarily impact a "trust" the government has maintained for over sixty years.

Does the trust fund have the funds needed to cover the shortfall?

Is this simply an election year gimmick by a president whose disapproval ratings have broken all past records?

Comment: Surely the government could reimburse this trust for any lost revenue if deemed necessary, or not?

Comment: Question could be rephrased to be less loaded.

Comment: "Does the trust fund ..." all the question you need. "Is this simply ... all past records" unnecessary, therefor I agree with bad-faith.

Answer (score 1):

The Congressional Budget Office(CBO) puts out an annual report on the Federal Highway Trust Fund. [It was already predicting a shortfall as of 2021](https://www.cbo.gov/system/files/2021-07/51300-2021-07-highwaytrustfund.pdf)

[image: CBO Highway Trust Fund projections (2021)]

> Under current law, the Highway Trust Fund cannot incur negative balances. However, consistent with section 257 of the Balanced Budget and Emergency Deficit Control Act of 1985, CBO’s
> baseline for surface transportation spending reflects the assumption that obligations presented to the Highway Trust Fund will be paid in full. The memorandum to this table shows the cumulative
> shortfall of fund balances, assuming spending amounts consistent with CBO’s July 2021 baseline. Following the rules for baseline construction, those amounts are estimated by adjusting the
> obligation limitations enacted under, the Consolidated Appropriations Act, 2021, by projected inflation.

The TL;DR is that the holiday will simply make these numbers larger. Congress will have to make up the shortfall somehow.

Comment: "Congress will have to make up the shortfall somehow." This somehow is not unknown. Typically a mix of making more debt, raising revenues or re-distributing spendings. Depending on how much larger these numbers get, it might be rather simple or more difficult. One should be able to estimate it. I heard the tax is 18 cent per gallon and about 135 billion gallons are used every year, so in 3 months the tax would have added up to something like 6 billion dollars, which is not a lot really and additionally this is what people save. The GOP would say: tax cuts are great unless others are doing it.

Comment: My understanding was that the use of debt to finance federal highway spending was prohibited in the original legislation.  It is supposed to be a pay-as-you-go system.